# Probability of two people being late

Tags: probability

Suppose persons A, B and C each have probability $1/2$, $1/2$ and $1/3$ of being late, respectively. What is the probability that two people are late?

**Attempt**

There are three cases to consider: AB is late, AC is late or BC is late. The probability AB is late is $1/2\times 1/2=1/4$. The probability AC or BC is late is $1/2\times 1/3=1/6$. Thus, the probability that two people are late is
$1/4+1/6\times 2=7/12$. Is my logic correct?

Comment: I do not know if you forgot the case that all three are late, or if we did not want to consider this case in the first place. In the first case, you have to add $1/2 \times 1/2 \times 1/3$; in the latter case, it is correct ;)

Comment: You are overcoming the case when all three are late.

Comment: Damn, of course. Thank you.

Comment: Should add: you are also assuming independence, which wasn't given.  Sensible,  since otherwise you can't say anything,  but it should have been specified.

Comment: @lulu This is true. For example, if person A is late then this has no bearing on whether person B is late. Is this what you mean?

Comment: Exactly.  Like I say,  you have to assume something or the problem is hopeless.  But things like that should be made explicit.

Comment: There are $2^3=8$ cases to consider (their probabilities will add up to $1$) , of which $3$ involve exactly two late people and $1$ involves three late people.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fear ... we have to do it in *threes*.

A and B are late but C is on time, A and C are late but B is on time, ... so and so forth.